# str_replace is replacing on one line, but not on another

Tags: php

I am running into a strange issue. I have the following code:

```
$foo = array(
        "some" => array(
            "foo" => "boohoo",
            "bar" => "foobar"
        ),
        "really" => array(
            "foo" => "boohoo",
            "bar" => "barfoo"
        ),
        "strange" => array(
            "foo" => "boohoo",
            "bar" => "foobarfoo"
        ),
        "occurences" => array(
            "foo" => "boohoo",
            "bar" => "barbaz"
        )
    );

$page = "";

foreach($foo as $bar)
{
    $subj = $template->loadTemplate('foobar', true);

    $str = "";

    $str = str_replace("{foo}", $bar['foo'], $subj);
    $str = str_replace("{bar}", $bar['bar'], $subj);

    $page .= $str;
}
```

The issue here is that when the PHP Code is run, {bar} is replaced in my template but not {foo}. I switched the two `str_replace` lines around and I got a different result -- {foo} is replaced but {bar} isn't! I've also tried swapping it for `preg_replace` and nothing changed. For the record, the `$template->loadTemplate()` function performs no operations on the string loaded, it simply gets the template from a file.

My questions are: why does PHP behave in this fashion, and second, how can I overcome this limitation/bug?

Comment: You set `$str` to replace `foo` with `$bar['foo']` then overwrite it with `bar` &  `$bar['bar']`. 

Try using `$str .=`

Comment: If you mean set the second `str_replace` line to `$str .= str_replace...` then I have tried but it appends the entire template again (replacing correctly, in one template {bar} is replaced but not {foo}, then in the next {foo} is replaced but not {bar}, etc)

Answer (score 7):

You changing only one, because use same input string for both replaces:

```
$str = str_replace("{foo}", $bar['foo'], $subj);
$str = str_replace("{bar}", $bar['bar'], $subj);
```

Try this:

```
$str = str_replace("{foo}", $bar['foo'], $subj);
$str = str_replace("{bar}", $bar['bar'], $str);
```

Comment: I can't yet accept an answer (have to wait ten minutes), but this fixed it. Thank you, trust me to overlook something simple.

Comment: @Seabody take a look at Fez Vasta's answer. It might possibly improve performance. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

As said CORRUPT you are replacing the strings voiding the previous command.
I'd add that [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) supports `Array()` as parameter.

```
$str = str_replace(Array("{foo}","{bar}"), Array($bar['foo'], $bar['bar']) , $subj);
```

Comment: +1 for giving a solution that uses arrays as the search and replace parameters.